# Electron how to load Main Menu when mainWindow is severing external HTML

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

In electron I have read how to include the menu code typically in the index.html. But in my application I am loading an external website and would like to know how to do this.

```
'use strict';

var electron = require('electron');
var app = electron.app;
var BrowserWindow = require('browser-window');

app.on('ready', function () {

  var mainWindow = new BrowserWindow ({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    webPreferences: {
      webSecurity: false
    }
  });

  mainWindow.loadURL('https://example.com/');
  mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools();

});
```

I do not have control over what is served on mysite.net, so how do I make a custom menu in this case the Proper Way! I figure I could just do it in app.js but curious if that would be proper?

**UPDATE**

Here is how I exactly handled it if anyone is curious:

```
'use strict';

var electron = require('electron');
var app = electron.app;
var BrowserWindow = require('browser-window');

var Menu = require('menu');
var customMenu = require('./libs/custom-menu');

app.on('ready', function () {

  var mainWindow = new BrowserWindow ({
    width: 800,
    height: 600
  });

  mainWindow.loadURL('https://www.example.com');

  var template = customMenu.getTemplate();
  var menu = Menu.buildFromTemplate(template);
  Menu.setApplicationMenu(menu);
});
```

custom-menu.js:

```
exports.getTemplate = function () {
  var template = [
    {
      label: 'MyApp',
      submenu: [
        {
          label: 'Sub Navigation',
          click: function () {
            console.log('test');
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ];

  return template;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just use the [Menu](http://electron.atom.io/docs/v0.36.7/api/menu/#menu) module in your main process. Actually, `Menu` is part of the main process modules anyway, so I'd say this is indeed the 'proper' way to use it. The example in the docs calls it via `remote` to demonstrate the possibility of setting the menu via the renderer; but you can just call `Menu.setApplicationMenu()` from the main process directly.

Comment: nice just wanted to make sure i was doing it correctly. I am going to amend my question so that there is some demo on how I accomplished the process.